# Vue - get image src from API and show it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to setup a simple page in my Nuxt project where an image url is retrieved from my backend and should be shown on the Vue frontend. The problem with my code is that the image is not shown.

Here is what i tried:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="qr_code" alt="" />
    </div>
</template>

<style>

</style>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export default {
    ssr: false,
    data(){
        return {
            qr_code: '',
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.request_code()
    },
    methods: {

        request_code(){
            return axios({
              method: 'get',
              url: 'MY-BACKEND',
              withCredentials: true,
            }).then((response) => {
                this.qr_code = response['data']['qr_code']  
            })
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Here is an example of the image i'm trying to show: [https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test:test?secret=test=test](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test:test?secret=test=test)

The problem with my code is that the image doesn't load at all, but i don't understand why. If i try to set `qr_code: 'https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test:test?secret=test=test'` it will work. What's the reason for this?

Comment: if you console.log(response) what does that say ?

Comment: Here is an example: `{'data': {'qr_code': 'https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test:test?secret=test=test'}}`

Comment: there is no https:// at the beginning of the url ?

Comment: Yes there is. In the console, i'm also getting this: `GET https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test:test?secret=test=test 400`

Comment: ok, and when you inspect the HTML <img>  element in the browser what is the src ?

Comment: If i inspect it, it seems to be alright, the url is correct. But for some reason i get a GET 400 from google which seems to prevent the image from being shown

Comment: oh ok I misread the 400. So when you directly set qr_code it works, but when you set it with the request response you have a 400. that is weird. And that's exactly the same url in both cases, no typos ?

Comment: Exactly! I'm checking again for typos and cases, but i think they're equal

Comment: Well I don't know for now, maybe night will bring me some ideas. Maybe try to create a a reproduceable exemple on jsfiddle

Comment: try adding v-if statement. <img v-if="qr_code" :src="qr_code" alt="" />